# SubView doesn't want to fit into specified frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The the problem arises when i dynamically load subview from nib and add it to the current main view during `viewDidLoad`.

```
UIView *someView = // load from nib
someView.frame 
    = CGRectMake(.0, 
                .0, 
                kFormSheetWidth /* = 540.0 */, 
                kFormSheetHeight) /* = 576.0 */;
[self.view addSubview:someView];
```

It all happens inside FormSheet window, where `UINavigationController` instance was passed into `presentModalViewController`:.
But, someView always resizes itself to be by 220.0 larger and by 116.0 higher and thus doesn't fit into window.

someView nib looks like

UITableView
xx UIView
xxxx UITextInput
xx UIButton

All these views have `autoresizeSubviews == YES, clipSubviews == YES`.

It's very surprising behavior. Interestingly, when I set the frame of someView in `viewWillAppear:`, everything looks fine. What (where) should I look for to tackle this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this is landscape mode? (ipad I assume because of the dimensions?)

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, but its a problem for a lot of people. (if its not it I appologize)

UINavigationController's rootview doesn't handle the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

method like your code does, so you need to subclass UINavigationController and implement it like your view controllers so it doesn't always add the views in portrait.

Comment: You are not supposed to subclass UINavigationController. It says so in the first paragraph of the Overview section in the [UINavigationController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I personally think there is nothing wrong with subclassing but you are correct it does say that. Here is another similar question from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769844/uinavigationcontroller-shouldautorotate-no-subclassing

Answer (score 0):

Some view is resizing itself after you create its frame on the viewDidLoad.

What you should do, is set the `autoresizeSubviews` to NO or just set it's frame in the viewWillApear.